# failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ---- at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to get mongo db to store numbers 1 to 9999 fist it would store 0 to 1 and then 0 to 2 and so on....

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
    a += i + " ";
    add(a, i);
}
```

and I added another variable to the object to show the last number
and when I run this code:

```
var a = [];
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const dbName = 'numbzzz';

function add(item, lastnum) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const client = new MongoClient(url);
        try {
            await client.connect();
            const db = client.db(dbName);
            const addedItem = await db.collection('nunb').insertOne({num: item, LNUM: lastnum});

            resolve(addedItem.ops[0]);
            client.close();
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
    a += i + " ";
    add(a, i);
}
```

I got this in the log:

```
1
2
3
...
9999
(node:40664) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438
          new MongoNetworkError(
          ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:995:11
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:32:7
    at callback (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
```

so I basically get the error:

```
D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438
          new MongoNetworkError(
          ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:995:11
    at D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:32:7
    at callback (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\codde\mongoDB test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
```

can someone please help me with a solution. thanks :)

Comment: please help me with this...

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the connection was actively rejected because there is no process listening on the requested port.